# AjaxControlTookit AjaxFileUpload limit max file size

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there a simple way to limit the maximum file size allowed to be uploaded and update the statusMessage and State of the current file from the code behind to be displayed on the page? I'd prefer not to have to use the web config for this.

I've tried searching everywhere for this but cannot find it mentioned anywhere. I'm surprised it doesn't come as a standard property with the control...?! Unless I'm being blind?...

Comment: By default, without any settings, you will be limited to 4 megabyte attachments.  The control doesn't have this configuration because it is done at the web.config level.  Why don't you want to use the web.config to control this?

Comment: Because we have other areas that allow file uploads for different purposes, which would require different limits. This then also goes to different clients requiring different settings for each of these... you see where I'm going :(.

Comment: You may want to investigate third-party controls, then.  PlUpload is one I've used in the past, and I seem to recall it allowing file size limits in the markup.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks!